# How to execute a command when screen resolution changes in Linux

Tags: linux, xorg, arch-linux

I’m running Linux in a VM, and I want to run a script whenever the X server resolution changes (usually from going in/out of full-screen mode in the VM). How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

I stubled on another solution that was the result of [a similar question on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275365/how-can-i-run-a-script-on-resolution-change).

The author of the question wrote a small tool called **xeventbind** that hooks into the X-Events and thus does not need to poll for a resolution change all the time. This saves resources and ensures that the script is executed right after the resolution changed.

[The sourcecode and documentation of xeventbind can be found on GitHub.](https://github.com/ritave/xeventbind/)

Answer (score 2):

Write this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

Display* disp = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
Screen*  scrn = DefaultScreenOfDisplay(disp);
int height = scrn->height;
int width  = scrn->width;

int main() {
    std::cout << "width " << width << " height " << height << "\n";
}
```

Compile it

```
g++ test.c -o test -lX11
```

Run it

```
rbabchis@haze:~$ ./test
width 1920 height 1080
rbabchis@haze:~$
```

You'll have to modify it from there, or wrap it in another programming/scripting language to keep checking and execute your script on a resolution change. That should be easy.

Use this script to continuously check for changes and execute an external script (./external_script)

```
#!/bin/bash

resolution=$(./test)

while true; do {
        newResolution=$(./test)
        if [ "$newResolution" != "$resolution" ]; then {
                echo "Resolution change: $newResolution"
                resolution=$newResolution
                ./external_script
        } fi

        sleep 1
} done
```

Comment: Did this answer your question? Do you need more info?